# Error with Wordpress on Appserver

Tags: php, appserver, magic-quotes-gpc

`Appserver vrs:2.60`, and `PHP 6`, and now i installion Wordpress in my computer, but when i conccept address: `localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/setup-config.php` so it error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_magic_quotes_gpc() in C:\AppServ\www\wordpress\wp-includes\load.php on line 585.

And In line 585:

```
if ( get_magic_quotes_gpc() ) {
    $_GET = stripslashes_deep( $_GET );
    $_POST = stripslashes_deep( $_POST );
    $_COOKIE = stripslashes_deep( $_COOKIE );

}
```

And i use `Appserver 2.6.0`, 
`PHP 6`, 
`Wordpress 4.0.1`, 
`Mysql 6.0.4`

Comment: Patience. You posted this 7 minutes ago. Wow.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check you have enabled megic quotes in **php.ini**

```
magic_quotes_gpc = no
```

Also, ensure you have not turned it off in **.htaccess**

```
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
```

Comment: in php.ini i not found code: magic_quotes_gpc = no; and in .htaccess so